# Rust: dynamic struct properties dependent on const

Tags: rust, rust-macros

How do you define a struct with dynamic properties that depend on a `const` declaration in the body of the program?

```rust
const DIMS: u32 = 12;

struct Point {
   dim1: u32,
   dim2: u32,
   dim3: u32,
   dim4: u32,
   dim5: u32,
   ...
   dim{i}: u32 for each i in 1..DIMS
}

fn main() {
   let x = Point { dim1: 1, dim2: 2, dim3: 3, ... };
}
```

I suspect it involves a macro?

Comment: You can't pick the `DIMS` value from elsewhere in the program even with a macro. A procedural macro should be able to do it if you pass it the number as an argument, giving you a syntax like `#[derive (WithDims)] #[dims (12)] struct Point{}`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write macro which argument is number of dimension, it is impossible. If you want to dynamic size point, you should use `vec![]` or slice.

```rust
const DIMS: usize = 12;

struct Point {
   dims: [u32; DIMS],
}

fn main() {
   let x = Point { dims: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] };
   // Access dimensions with x.dims[i]
}
```

Comment: You misundertsand me: I don't want "to dynamic size point". The size is known at compile time: I just don't want repetitive code.

Comment: If it’s used at compile time, why not use an array? Like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=feefafccebf9f91436a85ac80ab86125)

Comment: because i need the struct properties to be all f64. this is a constraint of my use case.